# Remove ?___store &___from_store=default from the code url of magento 2 in multistore

Tags: configuration, url, magento-2.2.5, default

'Add Shop Code to URLs' to Yes in System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL options. But show ?___store &___from_store=default. I used magento 2.25. Thanks for help.

Comment: flush cache and reindex store,

Comment: @Vivek Kumar after fluch cache and reindex store show ___store &___from_store=default in url